# Change Result in SQL From Positive to Negative

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using the following code to insert data into a Temp table in SQL:

```
SELECT bartt_code, bartt_code_description, mele_port_name, expiry_date, trade_price, trade_qty_in_lots, trade_qty, (trade_price*trade_qty) AS 'Price_x_Quantity'
INTO #Table1
FROM kst_exchange_trade
WHERE bartt_code IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY bartt_code, bartt_code_description, mele_port_name, expiry_date, trade_price, trade_qty_in_lots, trade_qty
```

I am running into an issue where trade_qty should be negative when trade_qty_in_lots is negative. How could I build this in to my query to make this change?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

The `sign()` function will return a value that can be used to match negative/positive.

```
sign(trade_qty_in_lots) * abs(trade_qty)
```

If you can guarantee that `trade_qty` is always positive then naturally the absolute value is unnecessary and can be removed.

Answer (score 2):

If you only want to align the sign, you could always turn the `trade_qty` field into an expression, such as:

```
IIF (
    trade_qty_in_lots >= 0, 
            ABS(trade_qty), 
       -1 * ABS(trade_qty)
) AS trade_qty
```

Note, I've added in an `ABS` to cover all four cases:

- Both signs are positive
- Both signs are negative (not shown in question)
- `trade_qty` is positive, `trade_qty_in_lots` is negative
- `trade_qty` is negative, `trade_qty_in_lots` is positive (not shown in question)

Comment: @ThorstenKettner thanks, updated.